# Passing Variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have been trying to solve this and need some help. I have a user that logs in and I am passing that variable through Sessions. The main pages are templates that populate based on a key word search (I am passing the variable as a POST) and fill in based off of the information in the database.Now I am creating a way for the users to comment. Below is my basic form. I am getting stuck when i want to bring through one of the values of the database. I will call it $place for this explanation.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $place=$row['place'];}
<form action="post_comment.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="6" placeholder="Give Your Review!"></textarea><br/>    
<input type="submit" value="Comment" class="btn  btn-custom" role="button"/>
</form>
```

in the post_comment.php I have the following
    $query="SELECT displayname FROM Users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."' LIMIT 1";

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$name=$row['name'];

$query="INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment`, `user`, `place`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['comment'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $name)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $place)."'";

mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Can someone explain how to bring $place over to post_comment?

Thank you!

Comment: where is $place defined?

Comment: I have $place defined in the initial file. while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $place=$row['place'];

Comment: @tk1dgr1 Can you edit the post and add in the part where you declared `$place` and `$name`, thanks

Comment: If you have variables in you're first php page that you need to get to the post_comment.php page, you can either add them into the form as hidden values `<input type='hidden' name='place' value='<?= $place ?>'>` or add them to the session array if they are sensitive

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your `$name` variable.

However, for `$place`, you can use a PHP Session. Using a PHP Session is more secure than using a hidden field if you have sensitive information. Having a hidden field will allow users to manually edit the information by using Inspect Element.

`1st PHP File`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $place=$row['place'];}

session_start();
$_SESSION["place"] = $place;
```

`post_comment.php`

```
session_start(); //include at the start of your PHP Script

$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['comment']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["name"]);
$place = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION["place"]);

$query="INSERT INTO `comments` (`comment`, `user`, `place`) VALUES ('$comment', '$name', '$place')";
```

Comment: "This will work provided you declared all the variables correctly." i think this is the actual issue here, but we shall see

Comment: I think this doesn't address the question which is "how to access the `$place` variable which was created on a previous request"

Comment: Sending the variable on a session would break if page is loaded from cache e.g. Reopening chrome and tabs restore

Comment: Nevertheless, if the form is submitted straightaway, then it won't break

Comment: The form being submitted straightaway is something out of his control, he can't rely on that

Answer (score 0):

Guessing `$place` is an id, I would write it in the form as a hidden field, then you can read it also in your post vars.

So you would write your form like this:

```
<form action="post_comment.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="place" value="<? echo $place; ?>" />
<textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="6" placeholder="Give Your Review!"></textarea><br/>    
<input type="submit" value="Comment" class="btn  btn-custom" role="button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Users can edit the hidden field by using Inspect Element

Comment: Then add it to your `$_SESSION` array :D

Comment: Nevertheless he should check if user has permission to post on that place before inserting